# Is the scenario same or not for all the test cases

Tags: manual-testing

**First One:**

Scenario: Manager can log in into the login page (that is my one scenario next I move to the test cases)

For the above scenarios, I wrote the four test cases

First Test Case: Verify manager with valid user id and valid password

Second Test Case: Verify manager with in-valid user id and valid password

Third Test Case: Verify manager with valid user id and in-valid password

Fourth Test Case: Verify manager with in-valid user id and in-valid password

**My question is if I wrote four test cases of one scenario so the scenario is the same of all test cases or it will be changed to every test cases like;**

**Second One:**

Scenario: Manager can log in into the login page

Test case: Verify manager with valid user id and valid password

Scenario: Manager cannot log in into the login page

Test case: Verify manager with invalid user id and valid password

**Which one is correct?**

Answer (score 1):

First approach is correct, we can create multiple test cases for single scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Every software testing company follows the approach of creating test cases for the scenarios.

In the above statement, the scenario is the same for all the test cases, and writing all possible test cases for a single scenario is the best approach i.e the first one in your statement.

What is a test scenario? As a tester, you put yourself in the end user's shoes and figure out the real-world scenarios i.e a high-level understanding of the feature that needs to be tested. In your first statement, you have written one scenario and all the possible real-time test cases under it.

Answer (score 0):

Test Scenario is a general thing. many test cases can be derived from test cases.

In your example test scenario can be : Checking the login functionality.

While test cases can be:

1) Manager can log in into the login page with valid credentials

2) Manager cannot log in into the login page with invalid userid and valid password.

3)Manager cannot log in into the login page with valid userid and invalid password.

4)Manager cannot log in into the login page with invalid userid and invalid password.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach would help you out in case you want to manage a single suite to run a **Regression test** and **Smoke test**

> **Reason:** It contains negative and positive test cases in a single scenario

Your second approach would help you when you want to keep your **Smoke Test** and **Regression Test** separately

> **Reason:** It has different test scenarios of negative test cases and positive test cases. Hence you can execute a selective set of positive
> scenarios when you want to run the smoke test cycle and all scenarios
> when you want to execute regression test cycle

Select wisely..!

Happy Testing :)